# How do I write an optimization problem in compact form using SciPy?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization

[image: Model]

I am trying to implement a nonlinear program in python using SciPy. The problem is that my model involves a huge number of constraints and I want to know if there is a way to write it in compact form like you would do in other optimization software such LINGO.

The problem goes like the following:

```
Objective Function -> Min Z = (n : ℕ) : --(sum from k=1 to k=n) x(k)^2
s.t 
(for all values from k=1 to k=(n-1)) : x(k) <= x(k+1)
```

I have tried something such as:

```
def Objective(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(number of days):
       sum += x[i]*x[i]
    return sum
```

The problem is that this isn't working for some reason and for the constraints I have tried different methods and it keeps generating an error.

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output in your question?

Comment: I've added a picture to show the model. There are 2 decision variables and Cap(constant) and my expected outcome is the objective function value and the values of the decision variables. My main issue is that in LINGO for example I can write the model in compact form by using the @(For) and @(Sum) commands while here I haven't seen in the documentation anything resembling it and the model I'm doing contains numerous values and constraints which is I want to write it in compact form.

Comment: Answer by inspection: `a[j]=0, x[k]=0`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I meant >=

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be (significantly) 'compacted'. Move *x* outside of the innermost sum and you'll see that the constraint left side is equivalent to a scalar product of the sums of *x* and *a*. Further, the left side of the constraint doesn't change over *i* at all, which means that the right side should throw away all of its rows other than the `max()`.

This leaves us with:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint, NonlinearConstraint


def z(xa: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x = xa[:n]
    return x.dot(x)


def constraint_product(xa: np.ndarray) -> float:
    x = xa[:n]
    a = xa[-h:]
    return x.sum()*a.sum()


rand = default_rng(seed=0)

m = 5
n = 7
h = 11
Cap = rand.random(size=m)

A_monotonic = np.hstack((
    np.zeros((h-1, n)),
    -np.eye(h-1, h) + np.eye(h-1, h, 1),
))

x0 = np.full(n, np.sqrt(Cap.max())/n)
a0 = np.full(h, np.sqrt(Cap.max())/h)
xa0 = np.concatenate((x0, a0))

result = minimize(
    fun=z,
    x0=xa0,
    constraints=[
        LinearConstraint(
            A=A_monotonic,
            lb=0, ub=np.inf,
        ),
        NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=constraint_product,
            lb=Cap.max(), ub=np.inf,
        ),
    ],
)
print(result)
assert result.success

# validation
x = result.x[:n]
a = result.x[-h:]
print('x =', x)
print('a =', a)
for i in range(m):
    total = 0
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(h):
            total += x[k] * a[j]
    print(f'{total:.3f} >= {Cap[i]:.3f}')
```

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: 2.5145689445002967e-06
       x: [ 5.634e-04  5.159e-04 ...  1.791e+01  1.791e+01]
     nit: 23
     jac: [ 1.102e-03  1.122e-03 ...  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
    nfev: 443
    njev: 23
x = [0.00056337 0.00051586 0.00056337 0.00051545 0.00056474 0.00068027
 0.00075254]
a = [17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939
 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939 17.91043939]
0.819 >= 0.637
0.819 >= 0.270
0.819 >= 0.041
0.819 >= 0.017
0.819 >= 0.813
```

Importantly, though, note that this problem is unbounded in a logarithmic sense. The best solution is one where *x* approaches 0 and *a* approaches infinity. This can be observed by lowering `tol`.